# Error with VBA Type mismatch (Error 13)

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

my code:

```
Sub sem()
Dim f As Variant
Dim f1 As Long
Dim F2 As Long

f = Format(DTPFechaFalla, "yyyymmdd")
f1 = 20141227
F2 = 20150124


    If (f >= f1) & (f <= F2) Then
       Week = 1
       month = 1
    Else
       MsgBox "Fale"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the Type mismatch?

Answer (score 5):

```
If (f >= f1) & (f <= F2) Then
```

should be

```
If (f >= f1) And (f <= F2) Then
```

Answer (score -1):

The declaration of variable f is variant. But if you call the format function, the result is converted in a string. An then you want compare f1 of type long with a string. This is the problem. Compare f with f1 BEFOR you call the format function.

Comment: That is not the problem - some implicit conversion will take place.  E.g. `? 20141229 < "20141228"` is `False`, and `? 20141227 < "20141228"` is `True`